# What do I have to edit in pg_hba to allow only my ip adress acess the postgresql from pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Currently my ip adreess is 192.168.0.57 so I set up the pg_hba like this

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             192.168.0.57/32               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

But I got an error on pgAdmin. I set listen_adress to "*" on postgresql.conf. Is there a better way?

Comment: Where/how is pgadmin running?

Comment: is running on my local machine (ip 192.168.0.57). I want to connect to the remote host. I always used the 0.0.0.0/0 configuration but I have to stop doing that.

Comment: That’s a local address. What’s your public address?

Comment: What is the complete error message? **ADD as text as update to your question**.

Comment: @DanielA.White Ok, I placed my public ip address and it worked, I didn't know it but PgAdmin showed in the error message. Said that the ip adress wasn't allowed. If you want to add it as an answer...